# Can't use Droidparts' ClearableEditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, droidparts

I'm trying to use ClearableEditText as stated in the [Droidparts official doc](http://droidparts.org/widgets.html#clearableedittext) :

```
<org.droidparts.widget.ClearableEditText
     android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_action_remove"
     android:drawablePadding="12dp" />
```

But the component is not found, I get this error at runtime :

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.droidparts.ClearableEditText"

I'm importing the dependency like this :

> ```
> compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:3.2.5'
> ```

I looked at the content of the JAR and I don't find the "widget" folder.
[image]

Is the component not available anymore or am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, ClearableEditText belongs to :

> 'org.droidparts:droidparts-misc:3.2.5'

insead of

> 'org.droidparts:droidparts:3.2.5'

Comment: By looking at the url : (https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts/blob/master/droidparts-misc/src/org/droidparts/widget/ClearableEditText.java)